# need to output max and min (without array)

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program that prompts the user to enter integer numbers.
The program stops reading when user inputs 0.
It should output the max and min element among inputed numbers.
I must write it without using arrays.

**Input:** `1 2 3 4 5 0`

**Output:** `min=1 max=5`

My code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n,max,min;

    min=0;
    max=0;

    do{
        cin>>n;
        if(n>max){
            max=n;
        }
        if(n<min){
            min=n;
        }
    }
    while(n!=0);

    cout<<max<<endl;
    cout<<min;
}
```

The problem is that when I enter the integers from my example the output is `min=0 max=5`, instead of `min=1 max=5`.
How can I fix it?

Comment: @Devolus can i do without it?

Comment: When you initialize min to 0 and you compare it against i.e. 5 then what happens? Similar, if you init max = 0 and you enter -1 what happens?

Comment: `<limits>` would have what you want for the 'set min to the highest possible' and vice versa. Better yet, I'd just treat the first input as a special case and assign its value to both max and min. The comparison only matters in the context of the inputs provided.

Comment: As @sweenish said, the best way is to set `min = max = n` for the first input, then the you want to check for zero before checking `min` and `max` https://onlinegdb.com/rkdcqUFfu

Comment: The trick is to input the first number, and assign to both `min` and `max`, then start the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to input a starting value first, then loop:

```
int main()
{
  int n, min, max;
  cin >> n;
  min = n;
  max = n;
  if (n != 0)
  {
    while (cin >> n)
    {
       if (n == 0) break;
       if (n > max) max = n;
       if (n < min) min = n;
    }
  }
  std::cout << "min: " << min << ", max: " << max << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

In the code above, the first value is read and checked for 0.  The program stops input if the value is zero.

The minimum and maximum are assigned the first value.

Then the loop starts.